# Python requests except

Tags: python, python-requests, except

Currently using requests to scrape specific page using proxies along with ranges for page numbers, example

```
for page_no in range(1,10):
```

gives a range of 1-10

```
source = requests.get('http://example.com/page={}'.format(page_no), proxies=proxy, timeout=5).text
```

requests page contents with given page number using proxy with a timeout of 5 seconds

```
except:
    print ("proxy is offline")
    continue
```

creates a exception incase proxy is offline

what it then does is continues to proceed with the new script using a new proxy provided by a list. However what will happen is if request was equal to page 1 and return a exception then it wont retry page 1 it will move try page 2 with a different proxy skipping page 1s content..

what I'm looking to or tried to do is

```
except:
    page_no = page_no - 1
    print ("proxy is offline")
    continue
```

which theoritically should do 2 - 1 = 1 going back to page 1 or the page it was originally on, so if page 9 throws a exception, then it will try to go to page 10 but the - 1 will send it back to page 9.. However that idea didn't work, so would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code currently looks something like:

```
for page in range(1, 10):
    source = requests.get(“url?page={}”.format(page))
```

Would something like this be what you’re looking for?

```
for page in range(1, 10):
    for proxy in proxy_list:
        try:
            source = requests.get(“url?page={}”.format(page))
        except:
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Comment: that's pretty much what I have written, problem is upon continue it goes to page 2 if it failed on page 1.. I need it to take a stepback upon failing example

request = example.com/page=1

proxy failed so continue

request = example.com/page=2

Comment: it failed on page 1 so it didn't get page 1s content, then just continues with onto page 2.. i need to say on except: range is -1 of current input so it will step back to page 1 if fails rather than skip ahead to page 2

Comment: @UniVPS I assumed your "except" clause was catching when the request failed. If not, how are you detecting it?